# Django cannot setup when not using manager

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am having a strange issue, hopefully someone has encountered it before.

I have a custom script located at `my_project/my_app/scripts/custom_script.py` -- My desired use case is to feed this script a filepath and have it process the file and load/modify some data within my database.

Here is a snippet from that script:

```
import django

def setup_django(env):
    if env == 'dev':
        settings = "my_project.my_project.dev_settings"
    elif env == 'stg':
        settings = "my_project.my_project.staging_settings"
    elif env == 'prod':
        settings = "my_project.my_project.prod_settings"
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid choice for --env argument: {}".format(env))

    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', settings)
    django.setup()


def main():

    env = 'dev'
    setup_django(env)

    # Do stuff with my script
```

When I run the above from within the same virtualenv as my project, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'`

Inside the settings file:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
]
...
```

It seems that, when I call `django.setup()`, it goes and parses my my `dev_settings` file and finds `my_app` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list, then tries to import it directly (e.g. `import my_app`). This will never work, because `my_app` is a sub-module of `my_project` (should be `import my_project.my_app`). Here is a sample of the directory structure:

```
my_project
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── dev_settings.py
│   ├── prod_settings.py
│   ├── staging_settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── **custom_script.py**
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
└── manage.py
```

This settings file seems to work fine with `manage.py`, both in `runserver` and `shell` (can find the `my_app` application just fine). However inside the `custom_script.py` all seems lost.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you need to access from `custom_script.py`. Are you talking about settings?

Comment: I need basic model access -- models.MyModel.objects.create(...), etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) to add custom scripts to your app so that all django configs get loaded up correctly.

In your `my_app` folder, create folder structure below

```
management/
   __init__.py
   commands/
      __init__.py
      my_command.py
```

In `my_command.py`

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('running custom command')
```

on your shell

```
python manage.py my_command
```